# ignore the last line from a csv file while loading into mysql table

Tags: mysql, csv

```
>     LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.txt' 
>     INTO TABLE tbl_name 
>     COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '|'  OPTIONALLY 
>     ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
>     IGNORE 1 LINES ( col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

I want to ignore the first and last line from the file. I am able to ignore the first, but what can I do about the last line

Comment: Why not just delete the row from the table when the load has completed?

Comment: does not solve my problem,the above query gives an error because the last line doesn't have sufficient columns.

Comment: Why not just tidy up the file before loading it? e.g. `head -n -1 /path/file.txt > /path/file-tidy.txt`

Comment: I need to maintain the file as it is...It is a critical file

Comment: You have the original as well as the one without the last line